# Is it possible to have a RV with characterstic function whose graph looks like $1-|t|$ on $[-1,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere?

Tags: random-variables, characteristic-functions

The title kinda says it all. I know it is possible to have a RV with its Ch function being the periodic triangular wave. This RV can be achieved via the Fourier transform and then converting the cosine of $+$ and $-$ to complex exponentials. But since my new function isn't even periodic, this method cannot be applied. Is there any other similar process to get the RV relating to the above mentioned Ch function?

Actually, I just want to find any RV whose ch function will be zero outside $[-1,1]$

Comment: @MattiP. That is the ch function, not density function

Comment: Okay, my bad, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac 1{\pi} \frac {1-\cos\, x} {x^{2}}$ is a density function on $\mathbb R$ and its characteristic function is $1-|t|$ for $|t| \leq 1$, $0$ for $|t|>1$.

Comment: Any insight on how you obtained it?

Comment: @Anvit Fourier transform your function, maybe? Fourier transforming is self-inverse.

Comment: @Arthur _almost_ self-inverse, maybe "essentially" self-inverse. Literally self-inverse _if_ restricted to _even_ functions (as here).